# Run Linux on RISC STi7105BKUD?

Tags: linux, embedded

I have this board with the STi7105BKUD chip on it, along with ram, flash, and a lot of I/O. 
[image]
Reading the documentation for this chip [(here)](http://www.st.com/en/digital-set-top-box-ics/sti7105.html) I can see it has the ST40-300 processor embedded into it ; its doc is right [here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/technical_note/ac/8f/05/35/eb/0c/43/67/CD17962725.pdf/files/CD17962725.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD17962725.pdf) and says it can run , among other systems, Linux. Architecture is RISC.

Is it possible to successfully run Linux on this board? 
How should it be done ?

Comment: First step would be to determine what the board is. You need to know how to install software on the board. (And also if anyone has prepared a Linux install for that specific board, doing that from scratch is a *lot* of work.) Unless you were planning on unsoldering the processor and putting it on your own board...

Comment: I do not have exact reference for the board, however it does not contain anything more than connectors and a power supply ! Seems like this is the whole system on a chip. Even HDMI goes straight to it ... but I'll have to check on the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitively is possible to run Linux on this SoC.
Although ST dropped official support and (unfortunately) removed a lot of useful info from STLinux website, a part of it (part of downloads) is available [here](http://archive.stlinux.com/).

A large number of old satellite and IPTV set-top boxes had STi7105, STi7109 or similar. All of them run Linux, and [Enigma2](https://kodi.wiki/view/VUPlus) was a popular choice for satellite boxes.

However, you must keep some things in mind:

1. STi7105 is almost 10 years old (introduced in September 2008)
2. It has a single core 450 MHz ST40 CPU (SH4 architecture)
3. It can't decode any of the new codecs, like HEVC
4. If you decide to port Enigma2 (which is the best this SoC can run), remember that it can be PITA and requires access to the current firmware in order to obtain ST231 multimedia blobs.
5. The most recent kernel that supports this SoC is 2.6.32 with patches from ST, released in 2009. I'm currently porting one STi7105 board (Albis STB-8000) to 4.15 but without any ability to properly debug kernel, it's difficult.
6. If the board manufacturer decided to lock down JTAG, UART and network access (tipical for vendor-locked satelite boxes with CI), you're out of luck and you can just dump the board because it's not good for anything.